# After playing a song when i press next song button a few times, app crashes and logcat is showing the error in Update_SeekBar thread

Tags: kotlin, android-seekbar

I want to create a music player. Everything works fine but when I press the next song or previous song button a few times (5 to 6 times) the app crashes.
Logcat is giving the error in line : currentPosition = mediaPlayer.currentPosition

```
updateSeekBar = Thread(Runnable {
            var totalDuration = mediaPlayer.duration
            var currentPosition =  0

            while (currentPosition < totalDuration) {
                try {
                    sleep(500)
                    currentPosition = mediaPlayer.currentPosition
                    songSeekBar.setProgress(currentPosition)
                }
                catch (e : InterruptedException){
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
        })
```

> Logcat Error msg: 2019-07-06 08:30:01.779
> 9951-10013/com.example.musicplayer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
> Thread-7
> Process: com.example.musicplayer, PID: 9951
> java.lang.IllegalStateException
> at android.media.MediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition(Native Method)
> at com.example.musicplayer.PlayMusicActivity$onCreate$1.run(PlayMusicActivity.kt:68)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
>
> Note: Line # 68 = currentPosition = mediaPlayer.currentPosition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing UI of seekbar from the non UI thread. So try with below code.

```
    updateSeekBar = Thread(Runnable {
        var totalDuration = mediaPlayer.duration
        var currentPosition =  0

        while (currentPosition < totalDuration) {
            try {
//                  Add UI thread here
                runOnUiThread(Runnable {
                    currentPosition = mediaPlayer.currentPosition
                    songSeekBar.setProgress(currentPosition)
                });
                sleep(500)
            }
            catch (e : InterruptedException){
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    })
```